# Change directory to usb drive without using variables

Tags: powershell

I have a problem to cd into my usb drive (F:) using PowerShell and I can't use variables becouse I am starting PowerShell with Start-Process. I tried using
`cd (Get-Volume -FileSystemLabel NameOfUsb).DriveLetter:`
and it almost works but "F" has a space after it and ":" is in new line so it spits out error.
Is there any way to do it? It don't have to be using that method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should include the full Start-Process line you are trying to run. However, this should do what you want.

```
cd "$((Get-Volume -FileSystemLabel NameOfUsb).DriveLetter):\"
```

Comment: I just found perfect combination for me without using $
`(Get-Volume -FileSystemLabel P4wn).DriveLetter + ':\'|cd`